# AWS S3 - The specified key does not exist. - for uploaded folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, object, amazon-s3, directory, sdk

When I'm **uploading** a folder to S3 bucket (drag and drop), I see that it is not considered as an object - I can't get it with its key (GetObjectAsync()), and ListObjectsV2Async() doesn't return it (I'm using the .net sdk).
When I'm **creating** a folder under a bucket I can get it and it appears in list of bucket objects.
What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have the concept of a 'Directory' or a 'Folder'.

Instead, the *full path* of an object is stored in its Key (filename).

For example, an object can be stored in Amazon S3 with a Key of: `invoices/2020-09/inv22.txt`

This object can be created even if the `invoices` and `2020-09` directories do not exist. When viewed through the Amazon S3 console, it will *appear* as though those directories were automatically created, but if the object is deleted, those directories will disappear (because they never existed).

If a user clicks the "Create Folder" button in the Amazon S3 management console, a **zero-length object is created with the same name as the folder**. This 'forces' the folder to appear even if there are no objects 'inside' the folder. However, it is not actually a folder.

When using the `ListObjects` command while specifying a Delimiter of `/`, a list of `CommonPrefixes` is returned. This is equivalent to what you would normally consider a sub-directory.